# Read 3rd and 4rd column and append to 2nd column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a attraction_stats_score data frame as below:

```
> attraction_stats_score[(1:2)]
                    TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1 TOTAL
1                              Orchard Road    41
2                                 Chinatown    23
3                              Little India    19
4                              Merlion Park    19
5  Singapore River (Clarke Quay/ Boat Quay)    17
6                             Raffles Hotel    11
7                 Singapore Botanic Gardens    10
8             Esplanade Theatres by the Bay     5
9               Integrated Resort (MBS/RWS)    33
10                                  Sentosa    17
11                       Gardens by the Bay    12
12       Singapore Flyer/ Flight Experience     8
13                             Night Safari     8
14                            Singapore Zoo     7
15                  National Orchid Gardens     5
16                         Jurong Bird Park     3
```

Now , I have country wise data in 3rd and 4th column for the same attractions.

How, can I merge the 3rd column with the already existing 1st and 2nd column ?

```
> attraction_stats_score[c(1,3)]
                    TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1 INDONESIA
1                              Orchard Road        49
2                                 Chinatown        13
3                              Little India        13
4                              Merlion Park        12
5  Singapore River (Clarke Quay/ Boat Quay)         4
6                             Raffles Hotel         2
7                 Singapore Botanic Gardens         2
8             Esplanade Theatres by the Bay         4
9               Integrated Resort (MBS/RWS)        24
10                                  Sentosa         9
11                       Gardens by the Bay         7
12       Singapore Flyer/ Flight Experience         4
13                             Night Safari         1
14                            Singapore Zoo         2
15                  National Orchid Gardens         1
16                         Jurong Bird Park         1
```

any guidance will be really helpful.

EDIT:

Finally I need:

```
TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1 TOTAL
    1                              Orchard Road    41
    2                                 Chinatown    23
    3                              Little India    19
    4                              Merlion Park    19
    5  Singapore River (Clarke Quay/ Boat Quay)    17
    6                             Raffles Hotel    11
    7                 Singapore Botanic Gardens    10
    8             Esplanade Theatres by the Bay     5
    9               Integrated Resort (MBS/RWS)    33
    10                                  Sentosa    17
    11                       Gardens by the Bay    12
    12       Singapore Flyer/ Flight Experience     8
    13                             Night Safari     8
    14                            Singapore Zoo     7
    15                  National Orchid Gardens     5
    16                         Jurong Bird Park     3
                        TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1 INDONESIA
    1                              Orchard Road        49
    2                                 Chinatown        13
    3                              Little India        13
    4                              Merlion Park        12
    5  Singapore River (Clarke Quay/ Boat Quay)         4
    6                             Raffles Hotel         2
    7                 Singapore Botanic Gardens         2
    8             Esplanade Theatres by the Bay         4
    9               Integrated Resort (MBS/RWS)        24
    10                                  Sentosa         9
    11                       Gardens by the Bay         7
    12       Singapore Flyer/ Flight Experience         4
    13                             Night Safari         1
    14                            Singapore Zoo         2
    15                  National Orchid Gardens         1
    16                         Jurong Bird Park         1
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following

```
temp1 <- attraction_stats_score[, c(1, 3)]
names(temp1) <- c("TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1", "TOTAL")

temp2 <- attraction_stats_score[, c(1, 3)]
names(temp2) <- c("TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1", "TOTAL")

df <- rbind(attraction_stats_score[, c(1, 2)], temp1, temp2)
```

***Update***

Based on your comment you can do the following, create another column with the name of the country.

The code then would be:

```
temp <- attraction_stats_score[, c(1, 2)]
temp$Country <- "All"

temp1 <- attraction_stats_score[, c(1, 3)]
names(temp1) <- c("TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1", "TOTAL")
temp1$Country <- "INDONESIA"

temp2 <- attraction_stats_score[, c(1, 3)]
names(temp2) <- c("TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1", "TOTAL")
temp2$Country <- "AUSTRALIA"

df <- rbind(temp, temp1, temp2)
```

Comment: Hi Dimitris_ps, I cant rename the headers, I will lose track of which score is for which country. I need to finally display it as a graph in Tableau

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Friends for your guidance,

I have accepted the answer. The rbind was giving an error as the column names were not matching. To keep a tab of the countries, I have added a country column.
The code is using a loop as there are 24 columns to be merged 
Its based on Dimitris code snippet:

```
#Finds the name of the ith column
newcol <- names(attraction_stats_score)[2]
temp1 <- attraction_stats_score[,c(1,2)]
temp1$Country <- newcol
names(temp1) < c("TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1", "TOTAL", "Country")
attractionname <- temp1

for (i in 3:24)
{

  newcol <- names(attraction_stats_score)[i]
  temp2 <- attraction_stats_score[,c(1,i)]
  temp2$Country <- newcol
  names(temp2) <- c("TOURISTATTRACTIONSITES1", "TOTAL", "Country")
  attractionname <- rbind(attractionname,temp2)

}

# Writing the scoring data to a file
write.csv(attractionname, file = 'C:\\Datasets\\attraction_names.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, you saved the day. Now I have a beautiful tree-map on tableau for each country.